# Не могу обратиться к $rootScope с другого контроллера в angularjs.TypeError: $rootScope.get_groups is not a function

Tags: angularjs

Я контроллере Controller2 создаю функцию  $rootScope.get_groups()

```
//код контроллера Controller2, находящегося внутри CoreController
    $rootScope.get_groups= function() {
        $http.get("/api/admin/get_groups").success(function (response) 
            {
                $scope.GroupsList=response;  
            }); 
    };

<body ng-app="TestApp" >
<div ng-controller="CoreController">
   <div ng-controller="Controller2"></div>
</div>

</body>
```

Потом пытаюсь вызвать эту функцию с другого контроллера, но пишет, что

```
TypeError: $rootScope.get_groups is not a function
```

Почему из $rootScopа не читается?

Такое впечатление, что когда обращается 2-й контроллер к этой функции- она вроде ещё не существует.

Comment: взгляните на мой ответ, должно помочь.

Answer (score 1):

`$rootScope` переменная/функция должны создаваться в `app.run`, если хотите чтобы она была видна глобально.

```
app.run(['$rootScope', function(){
    $rootScope.get_groups = function(){
    $http.get("/api/admin/get_groups").success(function(response){
        $rootScope.GroupsList=response;  
    }); 
}]);
```

Кстати говоря, подобные функции с запросами к `API`, удобно создавать фабрикой:

```
app.factory("GetGroups", function($resource) {
    return $resource("/api/admin/get_groups");
});


app.controller("someCtrl", function($scope, GetGroups) {
    GetGroups.get({ id: 1 }, function(data) {
        $scope.post = data;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Потому что тебе надо, чтобы второй контроллер (тот, из которого ты присваиваешь в $rootScope) создался и выполнил присваивание раньше, чем тот, из которого ты обращаешься к get_groups.
2. `$scope.GroupsList=response;` - это что-то не то, скорее всего. Потому что $scope принадлежит контроллеру, а $rootScope вечен.

Comment: Поставил $rootScope и даже закомментировал. -Всёравно. Как сделать, что б 2-й контроллер выполнялся позже?

Comment: @TwoRS Эм.. Они у тебя ожновременно существуют, или как? Советую переделать по-чемловечески всё это.

Comment: Сперва идёт создание 1-го контроллера  и там $rootScope функция. Потом соответственно 2-й контроллер. а как именно передалать?

Comment: @TwoRS, создание - это не в коде, а в разметке. Как переделать - откуда я знаю, ты ж вообще почти никакой информации не дал. Но что ты делаешь что-то не то, я уверен.

Comment: А... Я в разметке указываю "2-й" контроллер родительским- может из за этого? а "1" вложен в него. И как тогда быть?

Comment: @TwoRS, инстанс внешнего контроллера создаётся раньше инстанса вложенного.

Comment: А есть ли какая-нибудь функция, что б сослаться на значения, когда они будут инициализированы? типа $q или...что-то?

Comment: @TwoRS, а почему бы просто не проверить?